# How to Catch Events when drawing a polygon on Google Maps Data Layer

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

When drawing a polygon on a google maps Data Layer, I want to handle the events when a user draws the first point, second and subsequent points so that the UI can give different user guidance such as:

- no points drawn : "click to draw the first point"
- first point drawn: "click to draw the next point"
- second point drawn: "click to add another point or click on the first point to end"

When the closing point is drawn on a data layer using the Data Library there is an 'addfeature' event.
When the final point is drawn using the Drawing Library there are different events such as polygoncomplete.

To see if any events are emitted for the first, second and subsequent points, I used google sample code to display all the events and modified it to handle Drawing events on a Data layer. The new events are:

```
'addfeature': 'data layer event',
      'click': 'data layer event',
      'dblclick': 'data layer event',
      'mousedown': 'data layer event',
      'mouseout': 'data layer event',
      'mouseover': 'data layer event',
      'mouseup': 'data layer event',
      'removefeature': 'data layer event',
      'removeproperty': 'data layer event',
      'rightclick': 'data layer event',
      'setgeometry': 'data layer event',
      'setproperty': 'data layer event',
      'circlecomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a circle',
      'markercomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawig a marker',
      'overlaycomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawing an overlay of any type',
      'polygoncomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a polygon',
      'polylinecomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a polyline',
      'rectanglecomplete': 'This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a rectangle'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bunjil/gfp9qntx/9/

The event listener was also enhanced to also listen for data layer events - not just map events.

Looking at the events that are fired, and checking the documentation it appears there is no event for adding points while drawing a new polygon, just the mouseup event on the data layer.

While it would be possible to count the mouseup events, this might not be a robust solution.

I can see there are some events on polygons and polylines when adding or moving vertices but these only seem to exist once the polygon is created.

Can anyone confirm if this understanding is correct or if there are events I am missing something.

There is a related question that seems to confirm there are no events on the data layer or the map but you can listen for mouse events on the canvas.
[How can I listen for the start of a user drawing a polygon in Google Maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458226/how-can-i-listen-for-the-start-of-a-user-drawing-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately I think you are right. And that would indeed be very useful if such events would exist. There is an open feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3805 I suggest that you subscribe to it and maybe add a comment too, explaining what you would need. It was requested back in 2011... with the latest update from Google team in May 2015. You never know ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I posted a comment and voted for it. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like people have been asking for this since 2011.  It's the end of April 2018 as I write this and it still hasn't been added, so... that's unfortunate.

While not a fantastic solution, I did come up with a workaround that worked for my purposes.  My map is inside of a container div tag that is the same size as the map.  I added an onclick handler to this.

If you keep track of the map drawing manager's mode in your code, you should be able to count the number of times the click occurs, and use this info as needed.  Then on the `overlaycomplete` event, you could reset the count to zero.

If you need to get at the position of the event, as I did, you can use the event to get the pixel coordinates of the location clicked on the map:

```js
const onClickHandler = (event) => {
  const offset = event.target.getClientRects()[0];
  console.log("x", event.clientX - offset.left);
  console.log("y", event.clientY - offset.top); 
}
```

With the x and y pixel coordinate, you can get a lat and lng with (this deserves a credit, but I forget where I got it):

```js
const point2LatLng = (point, map) => {
  let topRight = map
    .getProjection()
    .fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  let bottomLeft = map
    .getProjection()
    .fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  let scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  let worldPoint = new google.maps.Point(
    point.x / scale + bottomLeft.x,
    point.y / scale + topRight.y
  );
  return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldPoint);
};
```

### Update: May 2, 2018

#### Using `mousedown` and `mouseup` event handlers instead of just `onclick`

I just encountered a nuance with this I figured would be helpful to share.  It looks like the Google maps drawing manager doesn't register a vertex when you are drawing a polygon if the position of your cursor changes by more than a pixel when clicking.  So, if you click to drop a vertex, then while holding the mouse down, move the cursor by more than a pixel before letting the mouse up, a vertex does not get dropped.

To deal with this, instead of using `onclick`, I needed to keep track of the position of the `mousedown` event and compare it to the position of the `mouseup` event in order to ensure it was within an acceptable tolerance.

In my code, I store the `mousedown` position (I'm using React, so I store it in my component's state).  Then in my `mouseup` event handler I have this guard clause before I carry out any vertex-was-just-added functionality:

```js
if (
  Math.abs(eventPosition.x - mouseDownPosition.x) > 1 ||
  Math.abs(eventPosition.y - mouseDownPosition.y) > 1
) {
  return;
}
```

I extracted `eventPosition` to a method so it could be shared between event handlers:

```js
eventPosition(event) {
  const offset = event.target.getClientRects()[0];
  const x = event.clientX - offset.left;
  const y = event.clientY - offset.top;
  return { x, y };
}

// const eventPosition = this.eventPosition(event);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is very ingenious, but may be quite complex to maintain.Still, if there is no alternative then this is a valid option. I note that the feature is available on Mapbox. See http://geojson.io

Comment: Oh, thanks for accepting the answer!  I agree this is complex to maintain and not super ideal.  Adding to the complexity, I noticed a nuance to this that needs to be handled.  I've updated my answer to include some info about it.