# How to count vertex drawing Polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polygon

I'm using Javascript Google Maps Version 3.50 and Vanilla Javascript.

I'm trying to count vertex when I'm drawing a Polygon on Google Maps. My request is: "How can I count the vertex while I'm drawing a Polygon?"

```
let drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl       : true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position    : google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
        },
    markerOptions        : {
        draggable: true,
        },
    polygonOptions       : {
        editable     : false,
        strokeColor  : '#00B700',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight : 2,
        fillColor    : '#00B700',
        fillOpacity  : 0.35
        }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
                 if ( shapeCodeInputVar ) shapeCodeInputVar.val(MAP_SHAPE_CODE_POLYGON);
                 if ( locInputVar ) locInputVar.val(fnGetLocation(polygon, MAP_SHAPE_POLYGON));
            });

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
                 currentOverlay = e.overlay;
                 drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            });
```

I've tried to use "overlayComplete". But it counts vertex after drawing.
Whenever I click mouse drawing Polygon, I want to count vertex.

Comment: There is no other available API event. The map `click` event won't fire when in drawing mode. You *could* use a standard click event listener on the document and check the drawing manager mode with `getDrawingMode()` which will return `null` when not using the drawing tools and `polygon` while drawing a polygon.

Comment: related question: [google map api v3 - how to limit number of polygon lines and force closure at the 5 click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895079/google-map-api-v3-how-to-limit-number-of-polygon-lines-and-force-closure-at-th), as @MrUpsidown indicates, you can't use the drawingManager, but you can count or limit the vertices if you don't use the drawingManager and create the polygon in your own code.