# Google Maps Count the number of paths and polygons

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to limit the users ability to create more than 2 polygons and more than 1 path.  I can programmatically add or remove specific drawing tools, but what I can't seem to find any documentation on is counting the number of polylines or polygons that exist on a map.

Here is some pseudo code to demonstrate the intended use:

```
If exists > 2 polygons and exists < 2 polylines then
    disable polygon drawing tool
else if exists < 3 polygons and exists > 1 polylines then
    disable polyline drawing tool
else if exists > 2 polygons and exists > 1 polylines then
    disable entire drawing tool
end if
```

Again, my question is specific to counting polygons and polylines on a map.  Does the Google API have this capability?

Comment: No, this is not part of the Google Maps JavaScript API.  But there is nothing keeping you from implementing it in your code that uses the API.

Comment: Releated question: [Google Maps Drawing Manager limit to 1 polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166546/google-maps-drawing-manager-limit-to-1-polygon)

Comment: In your example, I'm not seeing where you're actually counting the shapes.  Seems that you're just disabling the controls after any 'polygoncomplete' event (which, I already know how to do).  What I'm not clear on is programmatically determining how many of a shape (polygons or polylines) exist.  Also, when I'm drawing another shape (polyline) I need it to recognize when a polygon has been created and vice versa.  Even if I limited each to only 1 instance, when I'm drawing a polyline (for example), how would I make it check if a polygon already exists or not?

Comment: If you need a count, you need to write code to keep track of the polygons/polylines and count them.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution I'm after.  How would you determine if a polygon exists?

Comment: When the drawing manager fires the `polygoncomplete` event the polygon exists.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not totally following, but I'll continue Googling.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: your if-elseif is more complicated than is required. If the limit is strictly 1 polyline at most, and strictly 2 polygons at most

```
if (n == 2) {
//switch off polygon drawing tool
}
if (m == 1) {
//switch off polyline drawing tool
}
if (n == 2 and m == 1) {
//switch off drawing tool
}
```

where

- `n` is the count of polygons and
- `m` is the count of polylines,

In other words, turning off the polyline drawing is independent of how many polygons there are, and vice versa.

As to keeping track of `n` and `m`...

Probably best to create an object - let's call it `cf` - and `push` each user-created object to it (if the user-created object is the type of object you want to count), and then switch off the drawing tool if the length of `cf` exceeds the limit you want to impose.

So

```
 var cf=[];

 /* stuff to draw things on the map, resulting in a new object called kk */

 cf.push(kk);
 if (cf.length>3){
  // switch off the drawing tool
}
```

Since you want to impose different restrictions based on whether the object created is a polyline or a polygon, create 2 objects (say, `cf1` and `cf2`) and push kk to `cf1` if it's a polygon, and to `cf2` if it's a polyline... and change the if statement to reflect the different tests.

**Why not just iterate a counter rather than creating an object?**

I'm assuming that there's a point to the drawing of the polygons and polylines, and that you want to use/save/export them.

With the approach I've outlined, `cf1` and `cf2` can contain everything about each polygon, not just their geometry - the user who generated them, summary information about them, and all the other things you might like to store/export/display.

If none of that is required, then a counter would work just fine.

**inb4** '*using `cf.length` is kinda non-canonical in the JS world*'. Too bad. It works (except in corner cases that don't apply here) and it's parsimonious.

Comment: Thank you for this.  In your example, what does kk represent?

Comment: `kk` is the object created by the user - the polygon or polyline geometry, plus any attributes that are available or created (e.g., datetime, polygon title, user name/IP and so forth).

Comment: I have attempted to implement your suggestion here: http://pastebin.com/TLmipAzE (section surrounded by //), but I think I'm going about it wrong.  I've added an IF statement to detect whether the newly drawn shape type is a polygon or polyline, but I'm not clear on how to implement both simultaneously to catch both criteria.  I only seem to be able to monitor one at a time.  So, the result of meeting one criteria is to maintain only the opposite drawing tool - with my method I can never end up with the entire drawing tool removed (when both criteria are met).