# How to programmatically draw a polygon with google map DrawManager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drawing

I'm using the google map to define the areas of a city. A user draws a polygon to determine a desired area. To reach this objective, I am referring to DrawingManager article [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166546/google-maps-drawing-manager-limit-to-1-polygon). Everything goes well unit I want to update the registered area and draw the polygon. The path I would like to follow is using DrawingManager. This is my code. The code loads the map correctly ,but it does not draw my polygon based on give coordinates.

```
GoogleMap.prototype.initial = function (currentPolygonData) {
var self = this;
var triangleCoords = [];
if (currentPolygonData != null && currentPolygonData.length>0) {
    triangleCoords = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currentPolygonData.length; i++) {
        triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(currentPolygonData[i].Lat, currentPolygonData[i].Lng));
    }
}
var polyOptions = {
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#bb4446',
    fillColor: '#c37172',
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0.45,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true,
};

self.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
        draggable: true

    },
    polylineOptions: {
        editable: true,
        draggable: true

    },
    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    map: self.map
});}
```

Answer (score 1):

The datatype for a collection of LatLng should be an array of dictionary with keys as '*lat*' and '*lng*' for latitude and longitude respectively.

Hence in your code it should be

```
var triangleCoordsArr = {};
if (currentPolygonData != null && currentPolygonData.length>0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < currentPolygonData.length; i++) {
        triangleCoords = {};
        triangleCoords['lat'] = currentPolygonData[i].Lat;
        triangleCoords['lng'] = currentPolygonData[i].Lng;
        triangleCoordsArr.push(triangleCoords)
    }
}    
for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoordsArr.length; i++) {
    // Construct the polygon.
    var mTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoordsArr[i],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    mTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

Also, here this [reference link from Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_add) should be helpful for more info to solve your case

Comment: For some reason, each added polygon is set selected. And I can't see the way to change this.